# Cannot set up multiple virtual hosts via MAMP

Tags: mamp, virtualhost

I'm trying to set up virtual hosts for the projects in my MAMP htdocs folder. But I cannot create more than one, it seems. If, for example, I have this in my httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/first-project/public"
  ServerName first-project.dev
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/second-project/public"
  ServerName second-project.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

And I then point the browser to second-project.dev, it will show me the contents of first-project.dev. If I remove the v-host entry for first-project, then I can view second-project.dev with no problem. It doesn't like me having more than one entry, for some reason.

I have the following in my /etc/hosts file:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   first-project.dev
127.0.0.1   second-project.dev

255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Am I missing something? Maybe a setting in httpd.conf?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my own question. When establishing multiple virtual host entries, you need the following line before the entries:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Also, you need to establish the desired directory to replace the default localhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/"
      ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

My full httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/"
      ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sampleapp/public/"
      ServerName sampleapp.dev
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/simplewebsite/public/"
      ServerName simplewebsite.dev
</VirtualHost>
```